# Ember Controller extend not loading variables into template

Tags: ember.js

I've created a `mixin`, a `controller`, and a `template`.

```
// checkIn/index.js.handlebars
<div class="page-header text-center">
        <h2>
                Check in for
                {{#unless checkInSettings.loaded}}
                        <span class="icon-spinner icon-spin"></span>
                {{else}}
                        <span class="text-info">{{checkInSettings.programName}}</span> - <span class="text-info">{{checkInSettings.programStartDate}}</span>
                {{/unless}}
        </h2>
</div>
```

```
// controllers/check_in_controller.js
App.CheckInController = Em.Controller.extend(App.LoadCheckInSettings);
```

```
// mixins/load_check_in_settings.js
App.LoadCheckInSettings = Em.Mixin.create({
        init: function() {
                this._super();
                if (!this.get('checkInSettings')) {
                        this.set('checkInSettings', App.CheckInSettings.create());
                        this.get('checkInSettings').set('isLoading', true);
                        var self = this;
                        $.getJSON('/check_in/settings').then(function(data) {
                                self.get('checkInSettings').set('isLoading', false);
                                self.get('checkInSettings').set('programName', data.program_name);
                                self.get('checkInSettings').set('programAcademicYear', data.program_academic_year);
                                self.get('checkInSettings').set('programStartDate', data.program_start_date);
                                self.get('checkInSettings').set('loaded', true);
                        });
                }
        }
});
```

I am trying to load `checkInSettings` into the entire `CheckInController` and all its subcontrollers. I would like to see `checkInSettings` in my `checkIn/index` template, but it's not showing up.

What does work is if I create the controller:

```
// controllers/check_in_index_controller.js
App.CheckInIndexController = Em.Controller.extend(App.LoadCheckInSettings);
```

However, I want to load the settings for use in other areas of `CheckIn`, such as the settings page.

Is there a way to load this mixin for the all of `CheckIn`, in the controller or route, so that I can access `checkInSettings` from `index` or `settings`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a controller CheckInsIndexController. On that controller add these two properties needs: ['check_ins'], a checkinsBinding: 'controllers.checkIns.content'. Then you can use checkIns in your index template.

Comment: Do I need to explicitly define the `needs` and `binding` in a separate controller? I can't include it in the parent controller?

Comment: Yes, the controllers don't inherit anything from their hierarchy in the router. You need to excplicitly use needs. If it can be done globally, it isn't best practice and might confuse someone else looking in your controllers where their dependencies are being injected from.