# How should I go about implementing site settings into my Ember app?

Tags: ember.js

I asked a question similar to this, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464099/ember-controller-extend-not-loading-variables-into-template), specifically about how to implement specific settings for a specific controller. In short, I wanted to implement `checkInSettings` for the whole `CheckInController` so that my `index`, `settings`, and `reports` templates and controllers have access to the `checkInSettings`.

I did get my answer to that; however, I think that specific settings might be limiting and it would be better served by making a `settings` object or store, and defining something like `settings.checkIn` for the check in settings.

I've looked for resources online but haven't come up with many answers... So, **how should I best go about creating application wide settings, with sub settings for specific areas of my app?**

A note: I would like to refrain from using Ember Data since it is not Production Ready yet, and this app will eventually be consumer facing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ember Data is a different beast.  Store them on the application controller.  Or if you don't want o clutter the application controller, create a singleton instance of a settings controller and store them there.  (The same thing can be done just on the application controller, just use application instead of settings).

```
App.SettingsController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  someSettingOn: false,
  someOtherSetting: null
});
```

And then in other routes/controllers:

```
App.AnyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  anyMethod: function(){
    this.controllerFor('settings').toggleProperty('someSettingOn');
  }
})


App.AnyController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['settings'],
  anyMethod: function(){
    var setting = this.get('controllers.settings.someOtherSetting');
    console.log(setting);
  },
  anyProperty: function(){
    if(this.get('controllers.settings.someSettingOn')){
        return 'yes';
    }
    return 'no';
  }.property('controllers.settings.someSettingOn')
})
```

Comment: Will I be able to access `anyProperty` or `anyMethod` from a different controller, such as `CheckInController`?

Comment: Yes you can, but that wasn't what I was getting at, I was saying you could access someSettingOn or someOtherSetting from any route or controller